# Reaching a JS DOM object?

Tags: javascript, dom, tinymce

I've been trying to get to a child node in a DOM object, but just cant.

From `console.log(tinymce.editors);` i get the following in Chrome Development Tools console:

[image]

And I would like to be able to access dom -> doc -> anchors object. But if I try doing `console.log(tinymce.editors.dom.doc.anchors);` I only get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined

Actually going any further than `console.log(tinymce.editors);`, for example doing `console.log(tinymce.editors.dom);` results in

> undefined

What am I doing wrong? How do I reach future down the JS object?

Answer (score 2):

`editors` is an array, as shown by the `[` on the first line of console's output. You may access the first element's properties using

```
console.log(tinymce.editors[0].dom);
```

and

```
console.log(tinymce.editors[0].dom.doc);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but `console.log(tinymce.editors[0].dom);` still gives me undefined and anything future down gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You may also access an editor object the following using

```
editor = tinymce.get(0); // or
editor = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');



console.log(tinymce.get(0).dom);
```

usually should work to get the dom object. Using my Chrome browser javascript console it works fine.

Comment: That only gives me: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get'

Comment: So strange... still `undefined` when doing `console.log(tinymce.get(0).dom);` :(

Comment: works on my system. what does console.log(tinymce.get(0));  ?

Comment: Much strangeness... How can I see the object doing `console.log(tinymce.get(0))` or `console.log(tinymce.activeEditor);` or `console.log(tinymce.editors[0])` but if i add `.dom` I get undefined

Comment: which tinymce version are you using?

Comment: Latest I would guess? Im using the one thats included in concrete5. In source it says; `majorVersion : '3', minorVersion : '4.6', releaseDate : '2011-09-29'`. But still its just javascript, objects should work the same?

Comment: yes, they should. was just thinking about a pretty old version where dom might have been accessed in an other way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18452/discussion-between-thariama-and-jamietelin)